# Admob on Windows 8.1 Universal Build

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-phone-8.1, admob

I am making cocos2d-x application for Windows 8.1 (universal).

I would like to include Admob ads in it, but there is problem:

Cocos2d-x 3.7 creates pure C++ xaml project for win 8.1 universal while Admob SDK uses C#.

Any ideas how could I use Admob in this case?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I found so far it is IMPOSSIBLE to use C# libs from pure C++. You need to use WinRT C++ component to get access to native stuff.

It is possible to do so from C# project - C# calls C++ which calls C# and it works.